# How do you get Speech Studio to use a different resource ie S0 not F0

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, speech

I've created a Cognitive resource on the F0 tier and created models using the Speech Studio. I'm having issues with that (see other issue). So I wanted to try an S0 tier which I created. Now I can't work out how to get the Speech Studio to create models using the S0 resource. I'm not able to switch out of the models I've already created. I should be able to specify which resource I want to create my models in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to the setting panel by clicking the gear icon on the top right side of the nav bar, then you will see all your speech service accounts/resources. pick the one you want and click to go to your project view again.

[image]

Comment: Great thanks exactly what I was looking for. Not the most intuitive, so would never have found it.